# Display the gml:id of WFS layer as an attribute in QGIS

Tags: qgis, wfs, gml

I have loaded a WFS layer in QGIS and want to display the gml:id of the features in the attribute table. Is this somehow possible? 
I can see the gml:ids in other applications (ex FME).

Comment: Do you have an example WFS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if it's possible in the attribute table unless the WFS defines the identifier as an attribute.

You can check by doing a DescribeFeatureType request like:

```
http://services.sandre.eaufrance.fr/geo/zon_FXX?SERVICE=WFS&REQUEST=DescribeFeatureType&VERSION=2.0.0&TYPENAMES=sa:Sage&outputformat=text/xml;%20subtype=gml/2.1.2&
```

Which in this example gives:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<schema
   targetNamespace="http://xml.sandre.eaufrance.fr/" 
   xmlns:sa="http://xml.sandre.eaufrance.fr/" 
   xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
   xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
   xmlns:gml="http://www.opengis.net/gml"
   elementFormDefault="qualified" version="0.1" >
  <import namespace="http://www.opengis.net/gml"
          schemaLocation="http://schemas.opengis.net/gml/2.1.2/feature.xsd" />
  <element name="Sage" 
           type="sa:SageType" 
           substitutionGroup="gml:_Feature" />
  <complexType name="SageType">
    <complexContent>
      <extension base="gml:AbstractFeatureType">
        <sequence>
          <element name="msGeometry" type="gml:GeometryPropertyType" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1"/>
          <element name="CodeNatZone" minOccurs="0" type="string"/>
          <element name="NomZone" minOccurs="0" type="string"/>
          <element name="TypeZone" minOccurs="0" type="integer"/>
          <element name="EtatAvancementSage" minOccurs="0" type="string"/>
          <element name="TypePerimSage" minOccurs="0" type="string"/>
        </sequence>
      </extension>
    </complexContent>
  </complexType>
</schema>
```

So no gml:id defined as an attribute, which is reflected in the attribute table in QGIS.

[image: Attribute information in QGIS for selected WFS feature]

However, you can get to the gml:id for the selected feature in QGIS by looking at the *Derived* values > Feature ID

[image: GML Feature ID as derived property of selected feature]

Answer (score 2):

> unless the WFS defines the identifier as an attribute.

It "does" because this type derives from `AbstractFeatureType`

```xml
<extension base="gml:AbstractFeatureType">
```

which has `gml:name` and `gml:description`. Maybe the issue here is that QGIS does not support extension from other types.

EDIT: flagged a ticket https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/issues/42660

Answer (score 1):

You could use the **WFS 2.0 Client** Plugin from the Plugin Manager. If you load a WFS layer with this Plugin you normally get the gml:id displayed as the first field in the attribute table.

For further informationm see https://github.com/qgisinspiretools/qgis-wfs20-client-plugin